# Show JSON data in HTML using Backbone

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I've got an event in my view which on keyup does a fetch request to the TMDB api,

```
class Movieseat.Views.Moviesearch extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/moviesearch']
  el: '#moviesearch'

  initialize: (opts) ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render, this)
    {@collection} = opts
    @render()
    return

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(collection: @collection))
    return

  events:
    "keyup input": "doSearch"

  doSearch: (e) ->
    @collection.setQuery $(e.currentTarget).val()
    @collection.fetch()
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Movie()
    $('#movies').append(view.render().el)
```

This is my collection,

```
class Movieseat.Collections.Moviesearch extends Backbone.Collection

  url: -> "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=#{@query}"

  setQuery: (q) ->
    @query = q
    return
```

So if my input is `inception` this is the fetch request,

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=inception
```

As you can see in my view I'm append a template called `movies`. I would like to show all of the `original_title` from the fetch request in that template. And update the template when it changes.

Comment: What do you mean by `data from the JSON`? Are the `original_title` and `poster_path` properties of some of your models?

Comment: @Dethariel well I'm trying to show the data from the fetch `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=inception` In this JSON there's data like `original_title` and `poster_path` And I want to show that data in a template.

Comment: Why are you binding an event (`@collection.on('reset', @render, this)`) and then assigning (`{@collection} = opts`) after? You should be URL-encoding `@query` before throwing it into your URL. And `fetch` doesn't trigger a `'reset'` event unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, your collection holds elements of type `movie` or something like that. After you `fetch`ed the collection, it's models should contain the `original_title` and `poster_path`. Now you can use [pluck](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck) method to read all those properties. The code should look like that (javascript):

```
collection.on("sync", function() {
    myView.displayTitles(collection.pluck("original_title"));
})
```

---

#### Update

With this code update you posted, I'm wondering why don't you use those properties inside a collection's template. Given that your collection doesn't declare the type of models it contains, you cannot use the `@model.get('prop')` syntax, as `@model` is not a Backbone model. Try using

```
@model.prop
```

syntax instead.

Comment: I've updated my question to provide a bit more context, maybe this will help to clarify the case. Would the code you've prodived go into the views initialize?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma no, that's something you already have. Why don't you access those properties mentioned above in the `moviesearch` template?

Comment: Because I don't know how. If I use `<%= @movie.get('title') %>` in my movie template I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` error. So my problem is that I don't know how to connect the template to the collection.

Comment: That's because you should be using `@movie.original_title`, no?

Comment: First off thanks for taking the time to see if we can fix this problem. Secondly, If I use `<%= @movie.original_title %>` I still get the undifined error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'original_title' of undefined 
(anonymous function) 
(anonymous function) 
JST.movieseats/movie 
Movieseat.Views.Movie.Movie.render 
Movieseat.Views.Moviesearch.Moviesearch.doSearch 
jQuery.event.dispatch 
elemData.handle`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma how does your template look like? are you iteration through the collection? I mean something like `<%= _.each(collection, function(movie) { %>` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63550/discussion-between-dethariel-and-peter-boomsma).